# DataProvider in TestNG returns Data provider mismatch (Rest Assured)

Tags: java, arrays, automation, testng, rest-assured

my DataProvider method dataForPost is returning 2d array of objects and when running the @Test method I get a mismatch error, not sure what is the problem here.

The error missmatch occurs at the test method, I tried to debug but no clue:

```
FAILED: tests.VisionPointTest.testGen
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
[public void tests.VisionPointTest.testGen(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,long,java.lang.String,long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)] has no parameters defined but was found to be using a data provider (either explicitly specified or inherited from class level annotation).
Data provider mismatch
Method: testGen([java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1, int arg2, java.lang.String arg3, long arg4, java.lang.String arg5, long arg6, java.lang.String arg7, java.lang.String arg8, java.lang.String arg9, java.lang.String arg10])
Arguments: [(java.lang.String) ID,(java.lang.String) ARE,(java.lang.String) 125851827,(java.lang.String) 7.84198E+14,(java.lang.String) 468720000,(java.lang.String) male,(java.lang.String) 1982534400,(java.lang.String) Emirati,(java.lang.String) ,(java.lang.String) ALSHEHHI,(java.lang.String) AHMED SAEED ALI]
    at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:918)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:961)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:201)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
```

DataProvider Method:

```
@DataProvider(name = "data_ids")
    public Object[][] dataForPost() throws IOException{
        
    int numFiles = search("C:\\Users\\LP\\eclipse-workspace\\RestAssuredAutomation\\Request_Files");
    String names[] = searchnames("C:\\Users\\LP\\eclipse-workspace\\RestAssuredAutomation\\Request_Files");
    String jsons[] = new String[numFiles];
    for (int i=0; i<=numFiles - 1;i++) {
        byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Request_Files\\" + names[i]));
        String inputrval = new String(b);
        jsons[i] = inputrval;
    }
    
    String excelPath = "./MyData/IDsData.xlsx";
    String sheetName = "Data";
    ExcelUtils excel = new ExcelUtils(excelPath,sheetName);
    
    //System.out.println(ExcelUtils.getRowCount());
    int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowCount();
    Object data[][] = new Object[rowCount][11];
    
    for(int i=0; i<=rowCount-1;i++) {
        data[i][0] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 0);
        data[i][1] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 1);
        data[i][2] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 2);
        data[i][3] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 3);
        data[i][4] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 4);
        data[i][5] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 5);
        data[i][6] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 6);
        data[i][7] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 7);
        data[i][8] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 8);
        data[i][9] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 9);
        data[i][10] = ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 10);
    }
    
    return data;

    }
```

Here is my @Test method:

```
@Test (dataProvider = "data_ids")
    public void testGen(String documentCode, String issuingState, int documentNumber, String optional1, long birthDate, String sex, long expirationDate, String nationality, String optional2, String lastName, String firstName) {
    
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        
        System.out.println(firstName);
          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you see is caused by the data-type mismatch, as the error suggests.

Let's break it down.

Your test method has the following signature:

```
public void testGen(String documentCode, String issuingState, int documentNumber, String optional1, long birthDate, String sex, long expirationDate, String nationality, String optional2, String lastName, String firstName)
```

In the exception you can see it:

```
Method: testGen([java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1, int arg2, java.lang.String arg3, long arg4, java.lang.String arg5, long arg6, java.lang.String arg7, java.lang.String arg8, java.lang.String arg9, java.lang.String arg10])
```

There is a diversity in parameter types: Strings, longs, ints.

But your data provider returns an array of strings, see the types near arguments:

```
Arguments: [(java.lang.String) ID,(java.lang.String) ARE,(java.lang.String) 125851827,(java.lang.String) 7.84198E+14,(java.lang.String) 468720000,(java.lang.String) male,(java.lang.String) 1982534400,(java.lang.String) Emirati,(java.lang.String) ,(java.lang.String) ALSHEHHI,(java.lang.String) AHMED SAEED ALI]
```

So your method waits for strings, longs, and ints, but receives all strings, therefore you have a 'Data provider mismatch'.

To resolve this issue you should either change the types of all test arguments to a 'String', or change the 'getCellData' in your data provider to smth like 'getIntData', 'getLongData' etc (not sure what methods are available to you), or just use Integer.valueOf/Long.valueOf where it is needed.

As a side note, I'd recommend you to create a separate class that will hold all the properties you are reading from the Excel, and then just build objects in your data provider, and pass them the Test. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40604434/23182657) about polyadic methods.