# RESTful Web Service Client - Pass Objects or only id of objects

Tags: java, web-services, oop, design-patterns

I have an web service application with an endpoint (`/car`) that returns a list of available cars stored in a DB. Then the same application has another endpoint that returns the value of a car on a given date.

When requesting the value of cars, should the client pass in a list of car ids or a list of car objects? For example, using Spring REST controllers:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/car-value")
public class CarValueController {
    
    private final CarRepository carRepo;
    private final SportsCarClient sportsCarClient;
    private final StandardCarClient standardCarClient;

    @GetMapping
    public Map<Long, BigDecimal> getTotalReturn(Set<Long> carIds, LocalDate valuationDate) {
       
       List<Car> cars = carRepo.findAllById(carIds);
       BigDecimal value;
       for (Car car: cars) {
           if (car.getType().equals(CarType.SPORTS_CAR)) {
              //get from value from sports car service
              value = sportsCarClient.getValue(car.getVin());
           } else {
              value = standardCarClient.getValue(car.getStandardId());
           }
           // put value in map
       }
       //return map
}
```

or

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/car-value")
public class CarValueController {
    
    private final SportsCarClient sportsCarClient;
    private final StandardCarClient standardCarClient;

    @PostMapping
    public Map<Long, BigDecimal> getTotalReturn(@RequestBody Set<Car> cars, LocalDate valuationDate) {
       
       BigDecimal value;
       for (Car car: cars) {
           if (car.getType().equals(CarType.SPORTS_CAR)) {
              //get from value from sports car service
              value = sportsCarClient.getValue(car.getVin());
           } else {
              value = standardCarClient.getValue(car.getStandardId());
           }
           // put value in map
       }
       //return map
}
```

This is question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136227/passing-whole-object-vs-passing-objects-property). I believe a few relevant differences are:

1. The client is another web service although located on the same physical machine and also maintained by the same developers.
2. The application with /car and /car-value endpoints connects to a DB that contains the car info (i.e. `Car` is an entity).
3. Some clients don't need the car type, VIN, or standard id. So, they would normally not store it when getting the car data from `/car`. If they passed `Car` objects to /car-value, they would have to start storing these values. They would need to know that these values are used to get the car value.

Comment: I would say, never trust your clients even if you are the client ;) ....maybe in the future someone will change something in the cars at the client and then your method do other things because in your database is a different state (example: other cartype than the given one). I would load the cars from database and work with THIS state.

Comment: Sending just a list of ids is better because it respects the DRY principle. If the client service has to send a `Car` object to your service, the car's definition on both services has to match (so you get code duplication and problems if you have to change/extend the `Car`'s interpretation). This decision will also allow you to test your code with ease. I would also use a `POST` endpoint and combine the date and list of ids into a single request body object.